# converting an array and separating by delimiter |

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following Javascript code:

```
const returnCodeList = conceptsComp.getWrappedInstance().returnCodeList()
                let companyList = []
                returnCodeList.map(concept => {
                    companyList.push(company.company_path)
                })
                console.log(companyList)
```

And the `console.log(companyList)` prints the following :

`Array [ "Company 11", "\\MNSCP_DX\\" ]`

Since, I am sending this value while calling a web service, I want to separate it like the following, separated by `|`:

```
            Company 11 | \\MNSCP_DX\\
```

Do I need to first convert the `companyList` array to JSON and then apply the separation logic?

Comment: `companyList.join(' | ')`

Comment: Granted this turns it into a string.  If you are wanting to make the array delimiter actually be "|", then that's not a thing in javascript

Comment: @Taplar I just want the output of `console.log(companyList)` look like `Company 11 | \\MNSCP_DX\\`.  Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, then you can just use join.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks and in some scenarios, it could be just `Array [  "\\MNSCP_DX\\" ]`, in that case, I want it to be like `\\MNSCP_DX\\` and then `companyList.join(' | ')` might not be a good option, right?

Comment: If it is a single element, nothing is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.join()`

```js
array1 = [ "Company 11", "\\MNSCP_DX\\" ]
 res = [array1.join(" | ")]
 console.log(res)
 
 array2 = [ "\\MNSCP_DX\\" ]
 res = [array2.join(" | ")]
 console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join like this:

```js
const returnCodeList = conceptsComp.getWrappedInstance().returnCodeList();
const companyStr = returnCodeList.map(({company_path}) => company_path)).join(" | ");
console.log(companyStr);
```

More about join:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

More about map:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map